# siunitx automatic line breaks for text in S column

Tags: siunitx, tabularray, s-column-type

I'm trying to typeset numbers into a table with a header row using the `tabularray` package and its `siunitx` library, but I can't figure out how to get siunitx' `S` columns to introduce automatic line breaks if the text in the header row becomes too long:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}
    {
    colspec = {*{2}{S[table-format = 1.1(1), table-column-width = 2cm]}},
    hlines,
    vlines,
    }
    {{{some numbers}}} & {{{some more numbers which require a detailled and intricate and also very long description}}} \\
    5.1 & 4.0 \\ 
    79.8 & 45.3
  \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `co` to set something like `X` column type, use `si` to set something like `S` column type.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec = {*{2}{Q[co=-1,si={table-format = 1.1(1), table-column-width = 2cm},c,m]}},
hlines, vlines,
}
{{{some numbers}}} & {{{some more numbers which require a detailled and intricate and also very long description}}} \\
5.1  & 4.0  \\
79.8 & 45.3 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]